# Is there a way to show all values corresponding to a value on x-axis in the tooltip of Google Charts linechart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, data-visualization

I have a simple linechart with 2 lines. On hover, I would like to display both y-values in the tooltip that appears. I know I can accomplish this by writing a Javascript function that creates a custom tooltip for every x-value on the graph, but this seems so redundant to do, especially when the graph gets large. Since Google Chart is able to auto-generate the standard tooltip which contain both the x and y-value I feel like there should be an option to do this with built-in tools, is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [setting `focusTarget` to `'category'`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#:%7E:text=In%20focusTarget%20%27category%27%20the%20tooltip%20displays%20all%20the%20category%20values.) will do the trick.

See [here](https://www.mscha.org/knmi/summer_graph.cgi) for an example that uses it.